# Creating a Flat File with each field separated by ~ using Biztalk server

Tags: biztalk

My application send an Xml message to biztalk via wcf service. This message in then converted to a flat file by Biztalk process(mapping, orchestration,Custom pipeline). The fields of each record(row) is currently separated by a space. But I want to create a flat file in which fields are separated by tilda(~).

For example:

```
Current Format

name1 address1 dob1
name2 address2 dob2

Required Format

name1~address1~dob1~
name2~address2~dob2~
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Flat File schema, change the Child Delimiter on the record from space to ~